# How to store the value as "Account Receivable

Tags: odoo

I want make almost like invoice, how I can save value from fields deposit account into account that I choose. where I can look the example code ? I am really-really confused

Comment: Please try to describe more clearly what you're trying to do. Perhaps a list of the tables and fields you want to change, plus how to calculate the field values. If you've written code that isn't working, I suggest you post the code and the errors.

Answer (score -1):

Well JC

From description i can say that you can over rider create and write of your model and you can put code which will do a account entry to the respective account you want.

Thank You.